# Android SDK Manager not running in OSX Mavericks

Tags: android, macos, sdk, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Studio and tried to open the Android SDK Manager and it only opens a white window, and nothing else.  I updated my java version, and tried opening through the terminal but still does the same white window and the process keeps loading and nothing happens. this SDK and tools was installed by the universal installer of Xamarin Studio itself.

I downloaded the SDK manually but the same thing happened; the ./android script stills loads the white window and nothing else.

Any help you can give me to be able to run the SDK manager would be appreciated.  I don't know what else to check and I can't bulid any Xamarin.android apps because of this strange malfunction.

Comment: yes it is installed and updated to the latest version for OSX.

Comment: I had to install Java after upgrading to Yosemite. Works without any problems.

Comment: I still have Mavericks(Xamarin is still too unstable in Yosemite so I'm waiting) and this is happening.  Don't know what else I can do right now.